# Split dataframe into multiple dataframes by grouping columns

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, bioinformatics

I have a dataframe of expression data where gene are rows and columns are samples. I also have a dataframe containing metadata for each sample in the expression dataframe. In reality my expr dataframe has 30,000+ rows and 100+ columns. However, below is an example with smaller data.

```
expr <- data.frame(sample1 = c(1,2,2,0,0), 
                   sample2 = c(5,2,4,4,0), 
                   sample3 = c(1,2,1,0,1), 
                   sample4 = c(6,5,6,6,7), 
                   sample5 = c(0,0,0,1,1))
rownames(expr) <- paste0("gene",1:5)
meta <- data.frame(sample = paste0("sample",1:5),
                   treatment = c("control","control",
                                 "treatment1", 
                                 "treatment2", "treatment2"))
```

I want to find the mean for each gene per treatment. From the examples I've seen with split() or group_by() people group based on a column already present in the data.frame. However, I have a separate dataframe (meta) that classifies the grouping for the columns in another dataframe (expr).

I would like my output to be a dataframe with genes as rows, treatment as columns, and values as the mean.

```
#        control   treatment1   treatment2
#  gene1  mean        mean         mean
#  gene2  mean        mean         mean
```

Comment: Mean for each gene per treatment? Does this mean for `treatment1` simply `expr["sample3"]` and for  `treatment2` simply `rowMeans(expr[c("sample4", "sample5"])`? This can be done with `colnames(expr) = with(meta, paste0(sample, "_", treatment)); m1 = expr["sample3_treatment1"]; m2 = rowMeans(expr[c("sample4_treatment2", "sample5_treatment2")])`?

Comment: @Friede yes! But in reality my problem is much bigger and I have 30,000 rows and 100+ columns. So, I don't want to do this manually.

Comment: Then I recommend to edit your toy data such that it mimics your real data accurately

Comment: @Friede strongly disagree. Small sample data that is easy to work with is far preferable. We want **minimal** reproducible examples. There are exceptions, like if the focus of the question is on computational efficiency then larger data may be needed to get accurate timings. But generally **minimal** examples [are](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/903061) [much](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) [preferred](https://r4ds.hadley.nz/workflow-help#making-a-reprex).

Comment: @GregorThomas we are talking past each other because I expressed myself badly. To be more precise, I have the feeling that the structure of `colnames(expr)` and sample names is more complex in the real data at hand compared to the toy data given.

Comment: Glad to hear you're not pushing for 30000x100 examples :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this. It's not entirely clear what you want to group by in the last step, but you can adjust that easily.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

expr |>
  mutate(gene = row.names(expr)) |>
  pivot_longer(-gene, names_to = "sample") |>
  left_join(meta, by = "sample") |>
  summarize(mean = mean(value), .by = c(gene, treatment)) |> 
  pivot_wider(names_from = treatment, values_from = mean)
# # A tibble: 5 × 4
#   gene  control treatment1 treatment2
#   <chr>   <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
# 1 gene1       3          1        3  
# 2 gene2       2          2        2.5
# 3 gene3       3          1        3  
# 4 gene4       2          0        3.5
# 5 gene5       0          1        4
```

Comment: Sure you can `... |> pivot_wider(names_from = treatment, values_from = mean)`. Row names are bad and I don't think you should use them, but if you really want to after doing the above pivot_wider you can tack `|> tibble::column_to_rownames(var = "gene")`

Comment: Thanks! I added `pivot_wider(names_from = treatment, values_from = mean)` to reformat output (i've edited my post since)

Answer (score 6):

An approach in base R which works for the particular toy data example given:

```r
colnames(expr) = paste0(colnames(expr), "_", 
                        meta$treatment[match(colnames(expr), meta$sample)])
vapply(unique(meta$treatment), 
       \(i) rowMeans(expr[grepl(i, colnames(expr))]), numeric(nrow(expr)))
#>       control treatment1 treatment2
#> gene1       3          1        3.0
#> gene2       2          2        2.5
#> gene3       3          1        3.0
#> gene4       2          0        3.5
#> gene5       0          1        4.0
```

**Data**

```r
expr <- data.frame(sample1 = c(1,2,2,0,0), 
                   sample2 = c(5,2,4,4,0), 
                   sample3 = c(1,2,1,0,1), 
                   sample4 = c(6,5,6,6,7), 
                   sample5 = c(0,0,0,1,1))
rownames(expr) <- paste0("gene",1:5)

meta <- data.frame(sample = paste0("sample",1:5),
                   treatment = c("control","control",
                                 "treatment1", 
                                 "treatment2", "treatment2"))
```

Answer (score 4):

A base R approach:

```
expr|>
    split.default(with(meta, treatment[match(names(expr), sample)]))|>
    lapply(rowMeans)|>
    structure(dim=3)|>
    array2DF()

        Var1 gene1 gene2 gene3 gene4 gene5
1    control     3   2.0     3   2.0     0
2 treatment1     1   2.0     1   0.0     1
3 treatment2     3   2.5     3   3.5     4
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a `data.table` approach with the same logic provided by @Gregor Thomas:

```
library(data.table)

expr_dt <- setDT(expr)
expr_dt[, gene := rownames(expr)]

meta_dt <- setDT(meta)

melt(expr_dt, id.vars = "gene", variable.name = "sample", value.name = "expression")[
  meta_dt, on = .(sample)][
    , .(mean = mean(expression)), by = .(gene, treatment)][
      , dcast(.SD, gene ~ treatment, value.var = "mean")]
```

```
   gene control treatment1 treatment2
1:    1       3          1        3.0
2:    2       2          2        2.5
3:    3       3          1        3.0
4:    4       2          0        3.5
5:    5       0          1        4.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's another approach in `tidyverse`, replacing sample numbers with treatments from `meta` by creating a named vector instead of `left_join()`, and also using `values_fn` within `pivot_wider()` instead of `summarise()`:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

expr %>% 
  tibble::rownames_to_column("gene") %>% 
  pivot_longer(-gene) %>% 
  mutate(name = split(meta$treatment, meta$sample)[name]) %>%
  pivot_wider(values_fn = mean)

#> # A tibble: 5 × 4
#>   gene  control treatment1 treatment2
#>   <chr>   <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
#> 1 gene1       3          1        3  
#> 2 gene2       2          2        2.5
#> 3 gene3       3          1        3  
#> 4 gene4       2          0        3.5
#> 5 gene5       0          1        4
```

<sup>Created on 2023-12-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>